# useEffect is dispatching an action infinitely even with dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm having an infinite dispatch when using dispatch  within `useEffect`.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { getTodos } from "../redux/actions"

const TodoList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos())
  }, [getTodos])

  const todos = useSelector(state => state)

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "75%", margin: "auto" }}>
      <h3>Todo List</h3>
      {console.log("mounted")}
      {todos &&
        todos.map(todo => {
          return <TodoItem key={todo.id} title={todo.title} id={todo.id} />
        })}
      {todos && !todos.length && <h3>There are no tasks to do. Add one!</h3>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

**sagas.js**:

```js
import { call, put, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects"

const apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/todos"

function getApi() {
  return fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
      throw error
    })
}

function* fetchTodos(action) {
  try {
    const todos = yield call(getApi)
    const todosList = todos.slice(0, 20)
    yield put({ type: "GET_TODOS", todosList })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error })
  }
}

function* todoSagas() {
  yield takeEvery("GET_TODOS", fetchTodos)
}

export default todoSagas
```

[image: check the log here]

Comment: Can we please see what the "../redux/actions" file looks like?

Comment: This might indicate your component is fully unmounting and mounting again after the dispatch, because a `useEffect` will fire on mount even with a dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

The saga itself is creating an infinite loop because you use the same action name “GET_TODOS” for both initiating the fetch and storing the results of the fetch.  The action that you `put` from `fetchTodos` will be picked up again by your `takeEvery`.

You want two separate action types, for example “REQUEST_TODOS” and “RECEIVE_TODOS”.  The request action has no payload, while the success action has a payload with the array of todos from your fetch.  Your reducer would ignore the request action (unless you want to use it to set a property like `loading: true`).  For the success action, your reducer will store the results of your fetch from the payload property.